# Support Action Bar Size changed after fragment transaction with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, fragment, toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I have an application with `supportActionBar` and 6 Fragments one of the fragmnet using 'CoordinatorLayout' with `AppBarLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout` the `ActionBar` of MainActivity size changing after the fragment transaction with  `CoordinatorLayout`.

[image: This is my original ActonBar Size]
[image: This is after few fragment transaction]

**This is my Toolbar layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
   android:background="#2e6caf"
   android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**This is my fragment layout with `CoordinatorLayout`**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/back1"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                />
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/p_picture"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/pic_holder2"
                app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/p_name"
                android:text=" "
                android:textColor="#f5f5f2"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:gravity="center"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I assume the container  layout is `constraintLayout`?

Comment: No container layout is LinearLayout.

Comment: Use either `Show layout bounds` or `Layout inspector` to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Removing this line:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

from CoordinatorLayout fixed my problem.